# UDP packets seems to be blocked by android 4.1

Tags: android, udp, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I've looked for hours and haven't found any solution.

I have a UDP server listening on a specific port (5000) that's working fine on Android 3.2, 4.0.3, or 4.0.4.
Recently, I tried it on a phone upgraded to android 4.1, and it seems it can't receive any UDP packet.

Indeed, I've reproduced the same problem with AVD Emulator:
Of course, I made mandatory redirections (redir add udp 5000:5000) to make it run successfully under android 4.0.3.
It's working fine in 4.0.3 emulator, but 4.1 emulator doesn't receive any UDP packet.

Because all of this, I can't think that it's a code problem.

I'm very frustated and don't understand why it's not running on android 4.1. I can't find any reason....

does anybody can help me ? Is there any restriction specific to android 4.1 that I'm not aware of ?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Yeah, I've confirmed the same thing, but I've yet to figure out why.  There was some talk of needing to use the multicast lock, which I tried, but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: This problem seems to have been resolved in Android 4.2.2

Answer (score 1):

I've been wrestling with this for months. Today I made a portable hotspot on my sony Xperia P and connected devices to it's WiFi as opposed to my land-line router. Voilà! Nexus 7 running Jelly Bean now receives every UDP packet.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue is due to strategy that you should use. In 4.0.3 seems you need to put udp send packet in thread. So just create a thread and put all the steps in it and start it.